# sql export to xml same values as one

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, export

i have a table named "Location" like this:

```
society  site  floor  room
---------------------------
 Apple  London first  office
 Apple  London first  Meeting
 Apple  London first  Conference
 Apple  London second  IT
 Apple  London second  HR
 Apple  Rome   second  CCM
 Apple  Rome   second  BM
```

i wont to export that table as xml in format:

```
<LocationData>
       <Society name ="Apple">
             <site name ="London">
                 <floor name ="first">
                     <room>office</room>
                     <room>Meeting</room>
                     <room>Conference</room>
                 </floor>
                 <floor name ="second">
                     <room>IT</room>
                     <room>HR</room>
                 </floor>
             </site>
             <site name ="Rome">
                 <floor name ="second">
                     <room>CCM</room>
                     <room>BM</room>
                 </floor>
              </site>
        </society>
</LocationData>
```

I'm using sql 2008. can you please help me? Thank you Regards.

Comment: you should try to write it by yourself. SO is not free codewriting site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this (I added one more society to show the `1:n` structure through all levels:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(society VARCHAR(100),[site] VARCHAR(100),[floor] VARCHAR(100),room VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('Apple','London','first','office')
,('Apple','London','first ','Meeting')
,('Apple','London','first','Conference')
,('Apple','London','second','IT')
,('Apple','London','second','HR')
,('Apple','Rome','second','CCM')
,('Apple','Rome','second','BMD')
,('Orange','Vienna','first','Test');

SELECT m1.society AS [@name]
      ,(
        SELECT m2.[site] AS [@name]
              ,(
                SELECT m3.[floor] AS [@name]
                      ,(
                        SELECT m4.room
                        FROM @mockup AS m4
                        WHERE m4.society=m1.society AND m4.[site]=m2.[site] AND m4.[floor]=m3.[floor] 
                        GROUP BY m4.room
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                       )
                FROM @mockup AS m3
                WHERE m3.society=m1.society AND m3.[site]=m2.[site] 
                GROUP BY m3.[floor]
                FOR XML PATH('floor'),TYPE
               )
        FROM @mockup AS m2
        WHERE m2.society=m1.society
        GROUP BY m2.[site]
        FOR XML PATH('site'),TYPE
       )
FROM @mockup AS m1
GROUP BY m1.society
FOR XML PATH('Society'),ROOT('LocationData');
```

The result

```
<LocationData>
  <Society name="Apple">
    <site name="London">
      <floor name="first">
        <room>Conference</room>
        <room>Meeting</room>
        <room>office</room>
      </floor>
      <floor name="second">
        <room>HR</room>
        <room>IT</room>
      </floor>
    </site>
    <site name="Rome">
      <floor name="second">
        <room>BMD</room>
        <room>CCM</room>
      </floor>
    </site>
  </Society>
  <Society name="Orange">
    <site name="Vienna">
      <floor name="first">
        <room>Test</room>
      </floor>
    </site>
  </Society>
</LocationData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your sql server

SELECT * from Location
FOR XML AUTO

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay. I have tried that already but i get a report different. 
<location site="apple" floor="first" room="office">
<location site="apple" floor="first" room="meeting">
<location site="apple" floor="first" room="conference">
<location site="apple" floor="second" room="IT">
and so on....
is it possible to have the report as i described?

Comment: Hi, I would avoid `AUTO` mode... (at least if you know how to get the same with `PATH` mode). You rely on the cleverness of an engine, to analyse your data and find the *best* representation. This might work - or not...